# Freeing up memory outside of the function causes a double free or corruption error

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, memory-management

I am facing a problem where I get double free or corruption error when I try to free up a memory, outside of the function in which I had allocated that block of memory, even though I had passed the pointer to the memory block to a pointer outside of that function.

My code is such that in the `main()` function, I make a call to a function with the definition `char * reverseComplement(char * pattern);` as such:

```
char * rev = reverseComplement(dna_input);
```

where `dna_input` is a `char` pointer to a block of allocated memory that was allocated within `main()`. Within the `reverseComplement()` function, there is a line where I allocate memory and then return the pointer to that block of memory at the very end.

```
...
...
char * revcomplpattern = (char *)malloc(strlen(pattern));
...
...
return revcomplpattern;
```

One reason I thought could be causing the problem is that after the `reverseComplement()` function finished executing, its stack gets torn down so I would lose the access to the memory on the heap. But this shouldn't be because I had passed over the handle of the heap-allocated memory over from `revcomplpattern` which was residing in `reverseComplement()` over to `rev` which is residing in `main()`. So `free(rev)` in `main()` should do the job.

I don't know what I might be doing wrong here, and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `malloc(strlen(pattern))` --> `malloc(strlen(pattern)+1)`

Comment: It's not the best of habits to allocate memory in a function and them make it the caller's responsibility to call `free()`.

Comment: 1st of all, remove the cast, then see what the compiler tells you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've described so far (although @BLUEPIXY may have spotted a second problem).  One approach to solving problems like this is to repeatedly reduce your code, shrinking it to the smallest reproducible case, in order to find what line of code triggers the problem.  That should get you closer to figuring out what's going on (or at least being able to ask the next question).  That's how we used to solve problems like this before StackOverflow was created ;-)  Good luck!

Comment: Can't see check for NULL after `malloc`. Also `strdup` would be more expressive

Comment: Maybe some important pointer arithmetics is omitted?

Comment: One thing you can do (especially if you're not yet fully familiar with dynamic memory allocation/deallocation): Whenever you `free()` some pointer, set it to NULL - This at least gets rid of multiple `free`s. Other than that, use tools like *valgrind* to check for heap corruption and memory leaks.

Comment: @alk I removed the cast and compiled, nothing, the compiler didn't tell me anything, and even with the casts, the compiler never told me anything...

Comment: @tofro Following your suggestion, I used Valgrind, and when I had actually did the `free()` Valgrind correctly tells me that I do not have any leaks. But the double free error still persists! When I remove the `free()` and the error gets eliminated, Valgrind tells me then that I have one block of memory leaked! What's going on?!?!

Answer (score 0):

> ...where dna_input is a char pointer to a block of allocated memory that was allocated within main(). Within the reverseComplement() function, there is a line where I allocate memory and then return the pointer to that block of memory at the very end.

Your idea tells me that you are allocating memory and somehow using that memory in reverseComplement() function but in the function, you're allocating another block of memory. I'm not sure why.

> ...a problem where I get double free or corruption error...

You need to make sure all allocated blocks of memory in your program are freed by the time your program exits for any reason. If not, then you'll have a memory leak.

If you must allocate memory within a function (which I don't recommend), then you can use code like this:

```
char *getnewblock(int size)
{
    char *secondblock=malloc(size);
    return secondblock;
}

int main()
{
    char *myblock = malloc(1000);
    char *myblock2 = getnewblock(5000);
    free(myblock);
    free(myblock2);
    return 0;
}
```

The above program allocates 1000 bytes of memory then calls a function to allocate 5000 bytes of memory then frees both blocks of memory.

What I really recommend you do is allocate memory only in one function then use the same memory block in child functions like so:

```
void insertfirstchar(char *block,char onechar)
{
   block[0]=onechar;
}

int main()
{
    char *myblock = malloc(1000);
    insertfirstchar(myblock,'A');
    free(myblock);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, 1000 bytes are allocated, then a function is called to make the first byte of the memory block the letter "A" then the memory is freed. This last program can be used as your starting point.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought of doing too, but that'll make my `reverseComplement()` function have to take in an additional argument which I'd rather not do. Now I'm curious though, in professional projects, do they follow the practice you've suggested, or can my style be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I just got this all figured out! So sorry for the trouble! As it turns out, the error was not because of the way I was freeing my allocated memory, but at the `malloc()` call.

It turns out that what I did when I allocated

```
char * revcomplpattern = (char *)malloc(strlen(pattern));
```

was immediate followed by these lines

```
int strend = strlen(pattern)/sizeof(char) -1 ;
revcomplpattern[strend+1] = '\0';
```

where my goal was to ensure that `revcomplpattern` would be made into a string as I inserted a null termination at its end. Turns out that in indexing `[strend+1]`, I was actually touching an unallocated position in memory! After correcting the `malloc()` call with an additional space for one more character

```
char * revcomplpattern = (char *)malloc(strlen(pattern) + 1 * sizeof(char));
```

The call to the `free(rev)` does not throw an error! Everything works fine now and Valgrind shows no errors! Special shoutout to @tofro and @jdigital for your advising. When I used valgrind it started telling me there was an error in `strlen` and `malloc` which I couldn't understand at first until I narrowed it down to that line and gave a hard look at it and realized what was wrong.

Man, I feel that GCC gives very cryptic error messages that don't help much. I'm actually puzzled now, if anyone can answer, why my mistake DID NOT throw a SEGFAULT instead? I thought this would cause a segfault since I was touching an unallocated portion of memory???

Nonetheless, thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: `sizeof(char)` equals `1` by definition. If it weren't this `malloc(strlen(pattern) + 1 * sizeof(char));` would fail, as it should be `malloc((strlen(pattern) + 1) * sizeof(char));`

Comment: And still, if this really *is* C code just remove all those casts to `malloc()`, as it's not needed, nor recommended in any way. This is different from C++.

Comment: And finally: Writing out of the bounds of valid memory in C cause *Undefined Behaviour*. From this moment on *anything* could happen, with "*anything*" being a segmentation violation exception or simply nothing or ... or ...

Comment: @alk thank you for pointing out that it should be `malloc((strlen(pattern) + 1) * sizeof(char));`! But if say `sizeof(char)` was not `1`, then it would be something larger, say `4`, then there is no harm right? Its just that I would be allocating more space than I needed?

Comment: @alk Noted about the casting of `malloc()`. Its something that I've seen on many other discussions throughout stackoverflow. But the funny thing is that, this is how we've been taught in school! Like this is what they've been teaching in our introduction to programming and computing systems class. What's wrong with casting `malloc()`?

Comment: @alk Thank you for your last explanation about _undefined behavior_. I understand that now.

Comment: "*What's wrong with casting ...*" Do you do `int i = 1; long l = (long) i;`? Probably not, but let "implicit conversion" do its **well defined** work.

Comment: "*What's wrong with casting ...*"^2: Also please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/694576 and/or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565496/694576

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are corrupting memory before returning control to main()? Freeing your "valid" block of memory could be failing because your malloc heap is already corrupted.  Alternatively, maybe some error codepaths in reverseComplement() already free this memory?

Comment: "*Maybe, ... maybe ...*", maybe this answer would have suited better as a comment.